# Rsyslog eats up storage

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

I have set up rsyslog to grab various logs on my ubuntu 16.4 instance, but for some reason it eats up my storage until I have no free storage left. So far I couldnt find out what the issue is, also setting the rate limit didn't help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should install and setup [logrotate](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/logrotate/logrotate.8.en.html). It will compress the old logs, rotating them on a time/size base.

Comment: The thing is, it happens with in seconds. Does logrotate help for that?

Comment: If that happens *”in seconds”* then either you have **a lot** of log events or you’re doing something wrong like reading from log files that rsyslog is also writing to and creating an infinite loop ...

Comment: In fact its the /var/spool/rsyslog file which gets really big. It's 29G big.

Comment: Add the contents of `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and `/etc/rsyslog.d/*` to your question. `/var/spool/rsyslog`  implies your disk queues are filling up, which again implies an enormous event rate, or more likely you have an infinite loop.